# Unpredictable behavior of prisma orm function

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, prisma

I faced unpredictable behavior when used prisma.instance.update() function in my api. Here's some of the code:

```js
else if(allocationsGroupId != null) prisma.allocation.findMany({ where: { allocationsGroupId } }).then((allocations) => {
            
        const commonPercent = allocations.reduce((total, allocation) => total + allocation.percent, 0)

        Promise.all(allocations.map((allocation) => prisma.allocation.update({

            where: { id: allocation.id },
            data: { money: allocation.money + amount * allocation.percent / commonPercent}

        }))).then()
    })
```

If I don't call the .then() method when using the Prisma update function, it just doesn't update the database at all. So, I wrapped all of those promises in a Promise.all and invoked .then on that one promise. But the question is: Why do I need to use the .then() method for the promise to just resolve?

Comment: The promise doesn't need `.then()`. The code does need to await or return the `.all` promise so the code doesn't continue on before the promises have resolved.

Comment: But the synchronous code doesn't need to wait for promises to resolve. What's the point of asynchronous programming then?

Comment: The promises can be left to resolve in the background if their completion is not important to the flow.  Those promises should have a `catch` then, so you don't get unhandled rejections.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context to the function this code is running in?

Comment: Sure thing! This code is part of next js api route, which is an async function. The full code is open source and you can see it here: https://github.com/MindW1n/RobofinancierNextJs/tree/master. The code in this example is located in app/api/editLedgerEntry